# Why i'm getting "titlebarViewController not supported for this window style" exception when trying to add title bar accessory view

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

I'm trying to add title bar accessory view in app. For one of the beta testers i'm getting exception:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'titlebarViewController not supported for this window style'
```

Exception happens in this line:

```
[window addTitlebarAccessoryViewController:vc];
```

Any ideas what's causing it, can i somehow check for crash condition in code and disable adding title bar accessory view if that condition occurs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the exception happens when the window does not show title bar (`NSTitledWindowMask` == 0). So check for this can be done as follow:

```
NSWindow *window = self.view.window;
if ((window.styleMask &  NSTitledWindowMask) == 0){
    // Ignore if no title bar on window
    return;
}
```

But there was another issue in our code. When app was launch in full screen mode `self.view.window` was returning different window - `NSToolbarFullScreenWindow` as the view was part of the other title bar accessory view (toolbar) and in fullscreen it had different window parent.

Comment: Thanks! This just saved me. Was looking for whats wrong for about half a day.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the type of window and the OS X version I can't really help with the exception. You can however react to the exception.

See [Apple's documentation for Handling Exception](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html)

Comment: I do use try catch already. This does not help the crash though. Not 100% sure though if he has version with the try. But using it already.

Comment: You might need to find out what version of your app he is using along with information about window, titlebar and OS X version. Is he using the 10.10 unified titlebar and toolbar?

Comment: Yeah i already asked for more details, next version will have more logging as well. But was hoping someone had same issue on stackoverflow. So will be able to do fix faster.